# Webservices - Transport error: 302 Error: Found

Tags: web-services, https, apache-axis

I'm getting the following error intermittently when invoking the webservices over https using Axis2, any suggestions on this please?

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 302 Error: Found
```

I have tried almost all options available in internet,i.e, setting up the axis2.xml with configurations etc., but nothing seems to help.